# Can SWIG pointer classes be re-used across modules?

Tags: java, pointers, module, swig

Suppose I have two SWIG modules, and each declare %pointer_class(int, IntP);  Generating java code from them creates, say, first.module.IntP and second.module.IntP java classes.  I would like to use the same IntP class for both of these modules.

I attempted to define %pointer_class(int, IntP) in a commons.i file and import that module into the original two modules, but this didn't work.  I have to think this is a fairly common thing to do.